# Let $G$ be a $p$-group and let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Show that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and let $H < G$. Show that $H < N_G(H)$.

If $H \trianglelefteq G$, then it should be clear that $H<N_G(H)$. So we suppose, $H$ isn't normal. So we let $H$ act on the set

$$S = \{gHg^{-1}: g \in G, gHg^{-1} \neq H\}$$

via conjugation. If I can show that $p$ doesn't divide $|S|$, then I can use the fixed point theorem to complete the problem. Any advice on how to show that $p$ doesn't divide $|S|$?

Comment: $p$ doesn't divide $|S|$ since $p$ divides $|S|+1$

Comment: @kabenyuk I appreciate your input, but this result isn't intuitively clear to me. Can you expand upon this idea?

Comment: $|H^G|=|G:N_G(H)|$, where $H^G=\{gHg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}=S\cup\{H\}$

Comment: @kabenyuk Okay. Then by your first comment, does $|H| = 1$? And what is $|H^G|$ then?

Comment: The *total* number of conjugates of $H$ is the index of its normalizer, which is a power of $p$ because $G$ is a $p$-group. Here you are assuming the normalizer is not all of $G$, so the index is a nontrivial power of $p$. Your set $S$ contains all *but one* of the conjugates of $H$, so it is one less than a nontrivial power of $p$, hence mot divisible by $p$.

Comment: This is not right. For example a Tarski Monster is a $p$-group, but its subgroups of order $p$ are self-normalizing.

Comment: @DerekHolt
There are earlier examples of infinite $p$-groups in which a proper subgroup coinciding with its normalizer exists.

See e.g. [Baer's 1940 paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1940-047-03/S0002-9947-1940-0002121-0/S0002-9947-1940-0002121-0.pdf) example 3.4 on page 412 and remark on page 422.

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes I thought there were, but Tarski Monsters are the easiest to describe, even though it is very hard indeed to prove their existence. I find it irritating when people assume that the groups they are talking about are finite without saying so.

Comment: @DerekHolt I completely agree with the last one.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How do we know that $S$ fails to contain only one conjugate? What if there are more?

Comment: @DavidC.Huang: Why does that matter? If $S$ contains only one conjugate, then its cardinality is **certainly** not divisible by $p$. What I'm saying is that $|S|+1$ is a power of $p$ but is not $p^0$. Why does it matter if there are more? The point, **again**, is that $|S|+1$ is a power of $p$ different from $1=p^0$, so $|S|$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: @DavidC.Huang I do not understand what you are asking, or why you are asking it. How do I arrive at **what**? And why does it matter if the order of $G$ is a power of $2$? Are you under the impression that $2$ is not a prime? You **claim** in your post that all you need to do is show that the cardinality of $S$ is not a multiple of $p$. So why is it a problem if you get that the cardinality of $S$ is $1$? Is $1$ a multiple of $p$? Again, *what exactly is the problem?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is only true if $G$ is finite, which you are assuming but never state explicitly. As Derek Holt points out in comment, that is bad practice: if you are considering only finite groups, you should say so (or, in this site, at least **tag it** as `[finite-groups]`).

You state that you only need to show that the cardinality of $S$ is not a multiple of $p$ when $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$, so that is what the argument below will show.

Since you talk about the fixed point theorem, presumably you know about group actions. Let $G$ act on its subgroups by conjugation. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$.

Let $T=\{gHg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$ be the set of all conjugates of $H$. Your set $S$ is just $T\setminus\{H\}$. The set $T$ is the orbit of $H$ under the action.

By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, the cardinality of $T$ is equal to the index of the stabilizer of $H$ under the action. The stabilizer is
$$N_G(H) = \{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}.$$
Thus, the cardinality of $T$ is $[G:N_G(H)]$, and the cardinality of $S$ is $|T|-1 = [G:N_G(H)] - 1$.

Because $G$ is a $p$-group, every subgroup has order a power of $p$ and index a power of $p$. So the cardinality of $T$ is a power of $p$. Say $p^i$.

That means that the cardinality of $S$ is one less than a power of $p$. If $i\gt 0$, then $|T|\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so $|S|\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, Since $-1$ is never a multiple of a prime, then it follows that $|S|$ is not a multiple of $p$ and we are done.

If $i=0$, so $|T|=1$, then that means that $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$, so $H\triangleleft G$. Since we are assuming that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then this gives $H\subsetneq N_G(H)=G$, and we are done without having to worry about $S$ at all.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

1. Finite $p$- groups are nilpotent.
2. For any proper subgroup $H$ of a nilpotent group $G$, we have $N_G(H)\supsetneq H$.

Both these results are well-known.

The result is false without requiring the $p$- group to be finite, as Tarski monsters show.

Comment: The notion of nilpotent groups is a bit advanced for where I am. I advise submitting an answer that uses more elementary methods

Comment: Idk any other way to prove it off the top of my head.

Comment: I think the easiest proof uses the fact that $Z(G) \ne 1$ for a finite nontrivial $p$-group, together with induction on $|G|$.